# Apereo CAS 5.2.X how do I use a custom authentication handler

Tags: cas

Using jasig CAS 3.5.X, I had a custom authentication method. All I had to do was to add the class extending AbstractUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler in deployerConfigContext.xml and add dependencies in the classpath.

I can't seem to find the documentation on how to do this in Apereo 5.2.X. Any hints?

Found this 
https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.2.x/installation/Configuring-Custom-Authentication.html

but no info on constructor parameters...

Comment: Did you manage to get this working in the end?

Comment: @Newbee no. Moved on to more productive work.

Answer (score 1):

Having [this post](https://apereo.github.io/2017/02/02/cas51-authn-handlers/) as reference you have to follow these steps(quoted from provided link):

> 1. Design the authentication handler
> 2. Register the authentication handler with the CAS authentication
>      engine.
> 3. Tell CAS to recognize the registration record and authentication
>      configuration.

Create a class that extends `org.apereo.cas.authentication.handler.support.AbstractUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler`:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationHandler extends AbstractUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler {

// Constructor
    public CustomAuthenticationHandler(String name, ServicesManager servicesManager, PrincipalFactory principalFactory, Integer order) {
        super(name, servicesManager, principalFactory, order);
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationHandlerExecutionResult authenticateUsernamePasswordInternal(UsernamePasswordCredential credential, String originalPassword) throws GeneralSecurityException, PreventedException {
        // Your logic goes here
        return createHandlerResult(credential, this.principalFactory.createPrincipal(credential.getUsername()));            
    } 
}
```

Then you need to register your authentication handler to cas by adding it to a `@Configuration` class.

```
@Configuration
public class CustomAuthenticationConfigurer implements AuthenticationEventExecutionPlanConfigurer{

    @Autowired
    ServicesManager servicesManager;

    @Autowired
    PrincipalFactory principalFactory;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationHandler authenticationHandler(){
        final CustomAuthenticationHandler athenticationHandler = 
                new CustomAuthenticationHandler(
                        "CustomAuthenticationHandler",
                        servicesManager,
                        principalFactory,
                        0);
        return athenticationHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureAuthenticationExecutionPlan(AuthenticationEventExecutionPlan plan) {
        plan.registerAuthenticationHandler(authenticationHandler());
    }

}
```

The last step is to instruct cas to pick up your configuration class at runtime. This is done by adding your configuration class to `src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories`(if it does not exist, create it):

`org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=com.your_package.CustomAuthenticationConfigurer`

This is my working setup for 5.3.x version but I assume that it will also be valid for 5.2.x.

I have assumed that your are using `cas-overlay-tempalte` and `java`.